# Laravel whereRaw, orWhereRaw with FIND_IN_SET query not running specifically

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel, search

I have a problem in my project. I have comma seperated value in my database, I want to show data that is matching any of my selected box. But I did not get my result as spected

Here is my query

```
$products = $products->where('status', 1);
if ($request->get('connectivity')) {
    foreach ($request->get('connectivity') as $key => $connectivity) {
        if ($key == 0) {
            $products = $products->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(' . $connectivity . ',connectivity)');
        } else {
            $products = $products->orWhere(function ($query) use ($connectivity){
                $query->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(' . $connectivity . ',connectivity)');
            });
        }
    }
}

$products = $products->get();
```

My whereRaw query is running successfully but when the orWhere query is running then I get extra data.

My Database structure is
[image]

And my selectbox data example is [118, 112]

My Blade File from where the selectbox i check
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: how selected box look like and who data is stored in database can you  show some example

Comment: @OsamaAlvi updated my question. plz take a look

Comment: Just to be clear, what does `$request->get('connectivity')` look like? Also, what does `I get extra data` mean, exactly?  What is the problem?

Comment: @Don'tPanic The response data that is executed should be 12 item but I get 39 item after this query is excuted, My `$request->get('connectivity')` is an arry which is checked in Blade file

Comment: Sorry this doesn't mean anything to us. Why are you expecting only 12 items? What is wrong with the other 27 items?  We don't know your data, we can't tell what you expect or why.  Also we don't need to see a picture of your form, we need to see the data, eg the HTML, or better, what `dd($request->get('connectivity'))` looks like.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Because I check Only Bluetooth, Wired item which has 12 Product in My Database. So it needs to show 12 Item but The response shown 39 Item, Also the `($request->get('connectivity')` value is `[18, 12]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, 
$request->get('connectivity') has an array which looks like [118, 112].
You wanna filter products which contain any of these two values in their connectivity column.

You just need to create a where closure and run the loop inside it, not outside.

I created a table structure like this:
[image: Sample Table]

```php
$connectivity = [550]; # Similar to $request->get('connectivity')
$products = ProductModel::where('active', '1');
$products = $products->where(function($q) use($connectivity){
    foreach($connectivity as $key=>$c){
        if ($key == 0) {
            $q = $q->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(' . $c . ',connectivity)');
        } else {
            $q = $q->orWhere(function ($query) use ($c){
                $query->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(' . $c . ',connectivity)');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I dd()'d the result in the view which gives me 3 for [550].

[image]

For [550, 156] I get:

[image]